# smartcontrol: number of sectors written too small

Tags: ssd, smartctl

I tried to use smartctl to get info about the total bytes written to my SSD (started using it yesterday). It currently shows 18 Blocks which seems much to small for me (currently used space is ~9GB).

Is my interpretation of the "raw value" (number of 512B blocks) wrong?

EDIT:
Now (a day later) the value is 30 ... so maybe it is not measured in blocks but in GB?

Output:

```
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-linux-4.2.5-1-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
[...]
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4
```